# Flurl Posting with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, flurl

Good moring Team,

Since yersterday im trying to post an API using Flurl but im still getting this error and the post code block is not executed, i dont know where should be the issue.

bellow is my code:

```
public async Task<GetCustomerAcctsDetail_Model> GetCustomerAcctsDetail(string num_compte)
    {
        try
        {
            //getting fcub endpoint
            var customerdetail_api = Configuration.GetValue<string>("APIs:accountdetails");
            var api_key = Configuration.GetValue<string>("APIs:Authorisation_key");

          var customer_details=  await customerdetail_api
            .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .WithHeader("Authorization",api_key)
            .PostJsonAsync(new
            {
                channel_code = "MYCHANELCODE",
                account_no = num_compte
            })
            .ReceiveJson<GetCustomerAcctsDetail_Model>();

            return customer_details;
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(Ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
       

    }
```

i am always getting this error:

```
Id = 17, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

and the post is never executed.
can someone help please??

Comment: Please show us the full error include exception type. From what I can see there's a task that probably has to be awaited but isn't.

Comment: Hello @OliverWeichhold really the is no error from the code but the post block is ignored , its not executed and at  the end im seing this WaitingForActivation

Comment: i have updated the full methode pls @OliverWeichhold

Comment: are you by any chance calling `GetCustomerAcctsDetail(...).Result` ? this might be causing the execution to halt on the first async call within the method.

Comment: hello @CanBilgin im calling it like this:  var acctdetail = _Flexcube_Test.GetCustomerAcctsDetail("acc_number");

Comment: yeah that should be an await there right?  `var acctdetail = await _Flexcube_Test.GetCustomerAcctsDetail("acc_number");`

Comment: hello @CanBilgin thanks that was the issue, its fine now.